# Windows Azure without SCVMM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, hyper-v, azure-virtual-machine

We are planning to setup a new private cloud in our company. So we prepared 2 hyper-v host and 1 windows azure pack VM.

Is it really necessary to have System center Virtual machine manager to add the hyper-V host in windows azure pack portal?

Is it possible to add the hyper-V host without VMM? I have googled but unable to find any document to add the windows azure without VMM.

Please share your inputs for this issue.

Regards,
Loges